# Checking if string appears in list of objects in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am sending two queries from Django (v1.5.1) view to my template:

```
def my_view(request):
    query1 = auth.acc() # some api call
    query2 = Characters.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    rcontext = RequestContext(request, {'q1': query1, 'q2': query2})
    return render_to_response('api_character.haml', rcontext)
```

I'd like to check if a string from one query appears in the other query and check/uncheck my checkbox on the page accordingly:

```
<ul>
{% for item in q1 %}
  <li>
    {{item.name}}
    {# check if item.id appears in list of objects q2 (each q2 has its own q2.id property) #}
    {% if item.id in q2 %}
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    {% else %}
      <input type="checkbox">
    {% endif %}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Is it possible to do that in the template alone or should I write extra templatetag for this?

Comment: you could write your own template tag for this purpose. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In django 1.5, I would write that in views.py:

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "api_character.haml"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["query1"] = auth.acc() # some api call
        context["query2"] = Characters.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('id', flat=True)
    return context
```

or a function:

```
def my_view(request):
    query1 = auth.acc() # some api call
    query2 = Characters.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('id', flat=True)

    rcontext = RequestContext(request, {'q1': query1, 'q2': query2})
    return render_to_response('api_character.haml', rcontext)
```

but, what is wrong with the template? does it fail?

**EDIT**

Now I know what you want, review the code.
Note the `values_list`

(I like django class-based views, buy you can adapted it to a function)

Comment: The problem with template as it is in my example is that checkbox is just not checked, but is should be if `item.id` appears in any element in `q2`. Hm, rewriting my current view to TemplateView is a bit hassle I think... I suppose it will be much easier to do it in templatetag then...

Comment: I was just hoping it is easily solvable with a line or two in my template (and my current data I have).

Comment: so, you can see the input, but they are not checked?

Comment: I can see all input fields in my loop, but none of them is checked (`{% if item.id in q2 %}` condition does not pass at all). If i check my values, i see that `{{item.id}}` is some string (id of that particular row) and `{{q2}}` is a list of objects...

Comment: well, do you want to compare a 'id' (String) with a object of q2?  maybe you want to compare with a field of q2?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since I don't need an actual object in my template I solved this by sending list of `id`s to my template instead of list of objects.

```
def my_view(request):
    query1 = auth.acc() # some api call
    query2 = Characters.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    chars = []
    for ch in query2:
      chars.append(ch.id)

    rcontext = RequestContext(request, {'q1': query1, 'q2': chars})
    return render_to_response('api_character.haml', rcontext)
```

And the template code stays the same.

Comment: `chars = Characters.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('id', flat=True)` is better than a forloop

Comment: Oh, didn't know for `values_list` option! If you write this as an answer I will accept it since this does exactly what I needed =)